# How can i perform the following conversion?

Tags: java, string, swing

```
Formatter fmt=new Formatter();
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
fmt.format("%tc",cal);
System.out.print(fmt);
```

// Instead of `System.out.print(fmt);` i want to print the value of `fmt` on `JTextArea`.But as we know `JTextArea` accepts only String value.So how can i convert `Formatter fmt` into equivalent `String value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textField.setText(fmt.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`Formatter.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#toString%28%29):

```
Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
yourTextarea.setText(fmt.format("%tc",cal).toString());
```

Less code if you use [`String.format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) which creates a `Formatter` internally:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
yourTextarea.setText(String.format("%tc", cal));
```

If you plan on doing this multiple times, you also might want to use [`append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `setText()` as not to replace any previous content in your `JTextArea`, probably appending the value of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the leading line break like `println()` does.

Comment: instead of `\r\n` I'd recommend `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `fmt.toString()` which will give you a regular String (`System.out.print` does the same thing internally).